# Better way of inserting multiple strings in a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, import

So, I've got a few `txt` files, each container around 400,000 lines.

Each line is a word, I need to add to my database, if it isn't in there already.

Currently my code for checking/adding every word is

```
$sql = mysql_sql("SELECT `id` FROM `word_list` WHERE `word`='{$word}' LIMIT 1");
$num = mysql_num($sql);
if($num == '0'){
    $length = strlen($word);
    $timestamp = time();
    @mysql_sql("INSERT INTO `word_list` (`word`, `length`, `timestamp`) VALUES ('{$word}', '{$length}', '{$timestamp}')");
}
```

and the functions being called are:

```
function mysql_sql($sql){
    global $db;

    $result = $db->query($sql);

    return $result;
}
function mysql_num($result){
    return $result->num_rows;
}
```

I'm looking for a better way to insert each word into the database.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have access to the MySQL server's file system? What is in these text files--just the text, or do they have a timestamp or some other information with them on each line?  What access method are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of some ways to do this.

First, if you have access to the MySQL server's file system you can use `LOAD DATA INFILE` to create a new table, then do an insert from that new table into your word_list table. This will most likely be your fastest option.

Second (if you don't have access to the MySQL server's file system), put a primary key or unique index on `word_list.word`. Then get rid of your `SELECT` query and use `INSERT IGNORE INTO word_list ...`. That will allow MySQL automatically to skip the duplicate items without any  need for you to do it with a query/insert operation.

Third, if your table uses an access method that handles transactions (InnoDB, not MyISAM), issue a `BEGIN;` statement before you start your insert loop.  Then every couple of hundred rows issue `COMMIT;BEGIN;` . Then at the end issue `COMMIT;`. This will wrap your operations in multirow transactions so will speed things up a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code. It will first create query with all your values and you will run query only ONCE ... Not again and again for ever row

```
$values = array();

$sql = mysql_sql("SELECT `id` FROM `word_list` WHERE `word`='{$word}' LIMIT 1");
$num = mysql_num($sql);

$insert_query = "INSERT INTO `word_list` (`word`, `length`, `timestamp`) VALUES ";

if ($num == '0') {
    $length = strlen($word);
    $timestamp = time();
    $values[] = "('$word', '$length', '$timestamp')";
}

$insert_query .= implode(', ', $values);

@mysql_sql($insert_query);
```